# Weird white space in a java JFrame

Tags: java, swing, console, jframe

Here is my problem. 
When i use the following code:

```
package xyz.lexium.giapb.ui;

 import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ConsoleWindow extends WindowAdapter implements WindowListener, ActionListener, Runnable {

private JFrame frame;
private JTextArea textArea;
private Thread reader;
private Thread reader2;
private boolean quit;

private final PipedInputStream pin = new PipedInputStream();
private final PipedInputStream pin2 = new PipedInputStream();

public ConsoleWindow() {
    frame = new JFrame("GIAPB - Console");
    Dimension dimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int x = (int) ((dimension.getWidth() - frame.getWidth()) / 3);
    int y = (int) ((dimension.getHeight() - frame.getHeight()) / 3);
    frame.setSize(x, y);
    textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setEditable(false);
    JButton button = new JButton("clear");
    button.setBorder(null);
    button.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    button.setForeground(Color.white);
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(textArea), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.getContentPane().add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.addWindowListener(this);
    textArea.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    textArea.setForeground(Color.white);
    textArea.setBorder(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    button.addActionListener(this);

    try {
        PipedOutputStream pout = new PipedOutputStream(this.pin);
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(pout, true));
    } catch (java.io.IOException io) {
        textArea.append("Couldn't redirect STDOUT to this console\n" + io.getMessage());
    } catch (SecurityException se) {
        textArea.append("Couldn't redirect STDOUT to this console\n" + se.getMessage());
    }

    try {
        PipedOutputStream pout2 = new PipedOutputStream(this.pin2);
        System.setErr(new PrintStream(pout2, true));
    } catch (java.io.IOException io) {
        textArea.append("Couldn't redirect STDERR to this console\n" + io.getMessage());
    } catch (SecurityException se) {
        textArea.append("Couldn't redirect STDERR to this console\n" + se.getMessage());
    }

    quit = false; // signals the Threads that they should exit

    // Starting two seperate threads to read from the PipedInputStreams
    //
    reader = new Thread(this);
    reader.setDaemon(true);
    reader.start();
    //
    reader2 = new Thread(this);
    reader2.setDaemon(true);
    reader2.start();
}

public synchronized void windowClosed(WindowEvent evt) {
    quit = true;
    this.notifyAll(); // stop all threads
    try {
        reader.join(1000);
        pin.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    try {
        reader2.join(1000);
        pin2.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    System.exit(0);
}

public synchronized void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt) {
    frame.setVisible(false); // default behaviour of JFrame
    frame.dispose();
}

public synchronized void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    textArea.setText("");
}

public synchronized void run() {
    try {
        while (Thread.currentThread() == reader) {
            try {
                this.wait(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            }
            if (pin.available() != 0) {
                String input = this.readLine(pin);
                textArea.append(input);
            }
            if (quit)
                return;
        }

        while (Thread.currentThread() == reader2) {
            try {
                this.wait(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            }
            if (pin2.available() != 0) {
                String input = this.readLine(pin2);
                textArea.append(input);
            }
            if (quit)
                return;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        textArea.append("\nConsole reports an Internal error.");
        textArea.append("The error is: " + e);
    }

}

public synchronized String readLine(PipedInputStream in) throws IOException {
    String input = "";
    do {
        int available = in.available();
        if (available == 0)
            break;
        byte b[] = new byte[available];
        in.read(b);
        input = input + new String(b, 0, b.length);
    } while (!input.endsWith("\n") && !input.endsWith("\r\n") && !quit);
    return input;
}
}
```

It makes my console, but adds a white line between the text area and the border. How do i remove this

Comment: Let's see your [mcve] please.

Comment: So, you want the text placed at the bottom? Please provide a valid [mcve]

Comment: Its hard to see in the picture, but to the right of the text there is a white bar that divides the text area and the border. How do i get rid of this border?

Comment: Why are you re-asking the same question in comments and not addressing the question that now two people have posted?

Comment: Fixed it up so its easier to understand

Comment: Again, please take the [tour] and go through the [help], then learn [ask] and please post a valid [mcve] or [sscce](http://sscce.org/) which we can copy-paste and see the same issue as you, it should include all your imports and a main method, and still reproduce your issue. Note that we don't want code snippets or your whole code, we want a full simple program that shows your problem. Until then I'm voting to close this question because it lacks that runnable example we've asked for 3 times now (in my previous comment and @HovercraftFullOfEels comment) and still you haven't posted it yet.

Comment: Re wrote it....

Comment: *"to make people happy"* I'm not happy, who said that? Did you read the links provided? We don't need to know the logic of your program, just how the GUI is made, but anyway, I'll take a look at it. Again, I'm not happy because you never read the links I provided, that's not a [mcve] and that minimal example we're asking for is necessary to see your issue, we're volunteers, we don't need to spend more time than necessary solving **your** problems, and we take less time if you put effort into your question and help us to help you by posting compilable code, it's better for you and us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because a `JScrollPane` also has a border.

In this case you can remove it with:

```
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(textArea);
scroll.setBorder(null);
```

And adding the `JScrollPane` to your frame as:

```
frame.getContentPane().add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

But that will remove the border between the button and the text area

So you need to create a `MatteBorder` on the top of your `JButton`:

```
button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 0, 0, 0, Color.white));
```

So it will look like this:

[image]

I had forgotten to place how I ran your code in my own `main` method, because you forgot to add it as part of your [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

It will place the program on the [Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new ConsoleWindow();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're forgetting that the JScrollPane has a border.

```
frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(textArea), BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Set it to null.

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
scrollPane.setBorder(null);
frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

---

Another issue: this isn't Swing thread-safe:

```
public synchronized void run() {
    try {
        while (Thread.currentThread() == reader) {
            try {
                this.wait(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            }
            if (pin.available() != 0) {
                String input = this.readLine(pin);
                textArea.append(input);  // **************
            }
            if (quit)
                return;
        }

        while (Thread.currentThread() == reader2) {
            try {
                this.wait(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            }
            if (pin2.available() != 0) {
                String input = this.readLine(pin2);
                textArea.append(input);  // **************
            }
            if (quit)
                return;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        textArea.append("\nConsole reports an Internal error.");  // **************
        textArea.append("The error is: " + e);  // **************
    }

}
```

You're making `textArea.append(...)` calls off of the Swing event thread, and this can cause hard to debug intermittent exceptions to be thrown. Be sure to only append to this text component **on** the event dispatch thread.

Comment: Well look at that! Works. Sorry for being as some say... salty. VERY bad day. Thanks this did solve the issue!

Comment: You were faster than me to notice it, 1+

Comment: @MatthewParksJr.: please see edit regarding threading. And be sure to up-vote both Frakcool's and my answer as well as accept whichever answers the question most completely.